# Problems creating participants and identity issue - Authorization failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

After I run `stopFabric.sh` and `startFabric.sh` I want to create a participant and issuing his identity.

So I run

```
composer participant add -c admin@network -d '{"$class":"org.network.HrArena","HrArenaId":"rec"}'
```

which happends successfully.

And then I need to run:

```
composer identity issue -u rec -a org.network.HrArena#rec-c admin@network
```

And I get the error:
`fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]`

If I run `composer card list`

`┌─────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Card Name       │ UserId    │ Business Network │
├─────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ admin@network   │ admin     │ network          │
├─────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ PeerAdmin@hlfv1 │ PeerAdmin │                  │
└─────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┘`

How Do I overcome that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.
Everything works fine after I initially setup the Fabric / Composer networks.
However, after my Fabric containers are stopped and started again, I am unable to issue identities.  I am manually rebooting my host machine, and using Docker Swarm to restart the Fabric containers.

After reboot, `composer network ping -c admin@network` returns successfully, but `composer identity issue` (via CLI or javascript) both return code 20 errors exactly as you described.